# Trouble implementing google sso in AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, google-signin

So I have been trying to implement google single sign on into my angular application; however, sometimes when I reload the page the button disappear. My angular application is using angular routing. If I were to put my button outside of this it would work as expected. It just runs into problem when its loaded through a partial. Any idea how I can fix this?

```html
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
    <div ng-view></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @agektmr said, the problem is related to the way `angular` and `platform.js` interact with each other.

In order to use the auto rendered button you need to trigger the library when the `DOM` is loaded.

What I did is calling the following code in the `onComplete` method (I'm working with AngularMaterial dialogs, but you should be able to find a similar method quite easily):

```
$timeout(function() {
  $window.gapi.signin2.render('g-signin2');
});
```

The only difference is in your html you should change your `div` and instead of adding it a `g-signin2` class you should add an `g-signin2` id:

```
<div id='g-signin2' data-onsuccess='yourMethod'></div>
```

If you're willing to learn more about Google's implementation you could take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using imperative approach for implementing the button for this.

```
<div id="signin">
  <button>sign-in</button>
</div>
<script>
document.querySelector('#signin').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
  auth2.signIn();
});
</script>
```

Find more concrete example here
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/google-sign-in

The code you indicated didn't work because of timing. `platform.js` library tries to take care of it but fails because it's before angular renders DOM.